# why does InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() returns 127.0.0.1 in android .But works fine in JAVA program

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android application which can return IP address of the device connected to WI-FI network. when I use the code

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

In JAVA program it returns my IP as `10.160.2.197` (which is exactly what I want). But when I run this code in Android application it returns `127.0.0.1` The device is connected to a WIFI.
Some solutions in Stackoverflow suggest to use

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Is it not possible to get IP address using `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();`
if not then why?

> Here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Button b;
     private TextView t;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
         t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ip);
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
              getIp obj=new getIp();
              obj.execute()
           }
        });   
     }    

    class getIp extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>
    {

        String ip;

        public Void doInBackground(Void...params)
        {
             try {
                  ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              return null;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Void result){
            t.setText(ip);
        }


     }
 }
```

> Manifest contains following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior on Android.  Please refer to the javadoc for [getLocalHost()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()):

> Note that if the host doesn't have a hostname set – as Android devices
>   typically don't – this method will effectively return the loopback
>   address, albeit by getting the name localhost and then doing a lookup
>   to translate that to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permission for `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, this should work for you.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: but why does InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(); returns 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Because there's a different between local and external IP addresses.

Comment: then why does it give my device ip when i run it as JAVA program in eclipse?

Comment: Likely the Android app does not have a hostname set, this is normal behaviour. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost())

Comment: thanks a lot. finally got an appropriate explanation